# Meaning of " Gold sentiment distribution"?

Tags: nlp, sentiment-analysis, text-classification

What is the mean by " Gold sentiment distribution"?

I read few papers and they have mentioned about " gold sentiment distribution:
I tried to find it on google but I cannot find the explanation or meaning of gold sentiment distribution.

can anybody explain in simple words what is the meaning?

Thanks

Comment: Can you link to the papers, or show the sentence/paragraph where the term was used.

Comment: If it has a capital G then it might be a name. There was a linguist called Gold in the 60's who worked in very early semantic vectorisation. Just a guess!

Answer (score 0):

"Gold" here is short for "gold standard," so in this context it refers to sentiment tags that human reviewers have manually assigned to the data.

Examples:

- "[We introduce](https://books.google.com/books?id=l4VfDwAAQBAJ&pg=PA388&lpg=PA388&dq=We%20introduce%20the%20cross-entropy%20error%20between%20our%20predicted%20sentiment%20distribution%20and%20the%20gold%20sentiment%20distribution%20as%20the%20loss%20function%20while%20training&source=bl&ots=GBd0XMOnw8&sig=ACfU3U1V5E8A6aIsT9BAhc37my7jFZG1xQ&hl=en&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwj20pfo7KLgAhVKbK0KHb3fCscQ6AEwAHoECAkQAQ#v=onepage&q=We%20introduce%20the%20cross-entropy%20error%20between%20our%20predicted%20sentiment%20distribution%20and%20the%20gold%20sentiment%20distribution%20as%20the%20loss%20function%20while%20training&f=false) the cross-entropy error between our predicted sentiment distribution and the **gold** sentiment distribution as the loss function while training."
- "[We conduct](https://scholar.google.com/scholar?cluster=7210529374798616473&hl=en&as_sdt=0,15) experiments in a supervised learning setting, where each document in the training data is accompanied with its **gold** sentiment label."
- "[Three annotators](https://scholar.google.com/scholar?cluster=518764789948493705&hl=en&as_sdt=0,15) will label one candidate word and its **gold** sentiment is determined by majority."